# How to insert records from one table into another and insert with unique datetime value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to select values from one table into another and have each row inserted with a unique datetime entry.  The problem I am running into is that the GETDATE() or SYSUTCDATETIME() functions don't seem fast enough and I am getting duplicate datetime entries.

For example
    create table #T1
    (tnum int)

```
insert into #T1 select 1
insert into #T1 select 2
insert into #T1 select 3

create table #T2
(
Id int identity(1,1),
tnum int,
entrydate datetime
)

insert into #T2 SELECT #T1.tnum,  getDate() FROM #T1

select * from #T2
```

This results in the following

1   1   2014-10-01 11:14:15.673

2   2   2014-10-01 11:14:15.673

3   3   2014-10-01 11:14:15.673

My table design uses the datetime column as part of a unique index, and I need these to be unique. My desired results would be something like

1   1   2014-10-01 11:14:15.673

2   2   2014-10-01 11:14:15.674

3   3   2014-10-01 11:14:15.675

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Comment: "GETDATE() or SYSUTCDATETIME() functions don't seem fast enough and I am getting duplicate datetime entries." Don't you mean seem *too fast* as you're getting duplicate datetimes?  It sounds like you're attempting to use a datetime as a primary key or similar, is there a reason for this?

Comment: Why don't you use TimeStamp field?

Comment: Then fix your table design.

Comment: The example is perhaps over simplified to define my question, but I want an entry date which will be part of a natural index (note I am not referring to a primary key). There shouldn't be any reason to add a column such as sequence with the only purpose to make the rows unique. The main part of my question still stands - how can I insert unique datetime entries.  This is not a table design question.

Comment: Maybe it is not a data design question but it is a data design problem.

Answer (score 0):

The selection is fine, but you should use `datetime2` for the **column's** format, as it will allow you to store more precise time values.

`datetime2` has a precision of 100 nanosecs as opposed to `datetime`, which rounds it to `.003`, `.005` or `.007`

**UPDATE**

Or you wrap your insert statement in a while loop, where every step includes a few ms sleep.

I have created this fiddle, where you can see how this works (in MSSQL): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62f0d/2

Basically, the block is just as described above:

```
/* @i represents a number of transactions, it can be equal to a count(*) for example */

WHILE (@i <= 3)
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #results VALUES (@i ,getDate(), getDate())
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.002'
    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```